# When I upload large file and do another request to server it will wait until uploading finished. Can you prioritize okhttp request?

Tags: android, kotlin, okhttp

When I upload large file and do another request to server it will wait until uploading finished. Can we prioritize `okhttp` request so that while uploading and send another request, it will try to finish the later request first ?

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp does not support stream prioritisation like you are asking for. But you can achieve this by avoiding head of line blocking, and combining with some throttling strategy.

If you look at RequestBody https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/RequestBody.html

The simple implementation just writes the content from the file as fast as possible

```
    /** Returns a new request body that transmits the content of this. */
    @JvmStatic
    @JvmName("create")
    fun File.asRequestBody(contentType: MediaType? = null): RequestBody {
      return object : RequestBody() {
        override fun contentType() = contentType

        override fun contentLength() = length()

        override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
          source().use { source -> sink.writeAll(source) }
        }
      }
    }
```

Instead you could use something like this answer to achieve this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59883281/1542667

Comment: Nice answer, instead of throttle I can freeze the override fun read() to allow maximum bandwidth for other prioritized requests. Thank you!!